# SQL detecting partially duplicated rows

Tags: sql

I have a table like:

```
ID X
1  YES
1  YES
2  YES
2  YES
2  NO
3  NO
4  NO
4  YES
```

I need to return any IDs that have both `Yes` and `No`, so the final result should be, in this case, 2 and 4 but not 2 and 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ID
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE X IN ('YES', 'NO')
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT X) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select id from t
where x in ('YES', 'NO')
group by id
having count(distinct x) = 2
```

Here is a [working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02ee1/7)

Also note that if you only have 'YES' and 'NO' values in your table (as in your example) you can remove the where clause as it will be unnecesary and less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM myTable
WHERE X = 'YES'
     AND ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM myTable WHERE X = 'NO')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM t t1
  JOIN t t2 USING(id)
 WHERE t1.X = 'YES' AND t2.X = 'NO'
```